# C++: is it possible to make thread_local variable global?

Tags: c++, thread-safety

For example, I have a `thread_local` variable in my code, but there are a set of functions, which access and modify it. For modularity, I took out them to a different translation unit (correct me if I'm wrong on terminology), by creating a header with their declarations and source file with their definitions.

```cpp
// fun.h
int fun();
```

```cpp
// fun.cpp
#include "fun.h"

int fun()
{
    // Modify the thread_local variable here
}
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "fun.h"

thread_local int var = 0;

int main()
{
    // Modify the var in the main
    var = 1;
    // Modify the var by calling the fun() from fun.h
    fun();
}
```

What to do? How to access it from `fun()`? Isn't there a contradiction that global variables are common for all the threads of the process, but thread_local is local?

Comment: Same as any non-thread-local variable or function. You need to declare it in a header so the other files know it exists.  Thread-local is irrelevant to this problem.

Comment: Global variables are more a trap than anything else. They look like an easy solution to a problem, then later you notice while debugging that every freaking function in the program now could have a hard-to-spot side effect. If a value can be changed at any time by any thing, good luck easily isolating the problem!

Comment: @MooingDuck "*You need to declare it in a header so the other files know it exists*" - more accurately, you just need to declare it as `extern` in the translation unit that wants to access it.  That is *commonly* done using a header file, but that is not strictly a requirement.

Comment: Your main.cpp _depends on_ fun.cpp (i.e., it uses something that is defined in fun.cpp.) And now you want fun.cpp to depend on main.cpp. If you do that, you'll be creating a [_circular dependency_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency). No big deal in a simple exercise, but circular dependencies can lead to huge headaches when they occur in large projects. You should learn to spot them and eliminate them now—maybe save yourself some trouble later in your career.

Comment: P.S., in this case, maybe the best way to eliminate the circular dependency is also the simplest: recognize that they both belong in the same compilation unit. Get rid of fun.cpp altogether, and move everything into main.cpp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `var` is already global. "Global" refers to the scope of the variable: it means it is declared in the outermost namespace, so its use is not restricted to a particular block, class, or sub-namespace. So a variable can be both global and thread-local without any contradiction.

All you're asking for is how to allow this global, thread-local variable to be accessed by other translation units. Well, one obvious solution is to declare `fun` as `int fun(int& var)`, so in `main.cpp` you would call it as `fun(var)` instead of just `fun()`. If you do that, you might not need a global variable, and your code will be easier to reason about. But I'm going to assume you have a good reason why you can't do that.

If that's the case, you should provide a declaration of the variable in `fun.h`:

```
extern thread_local int var;
```

Now every translation unit that includes `fun.h` is made aware of the existence of a global variable named `var`, which is of type `int` and has thread-local storage duration. It is assumed that one translation unit, somewhere in the program, will provide a definition of `var`, and all other translation units are just referring to that variable. (Since it's a thread-local variable, this single definition creates a *set* of objects: one per thread.) In your case, that definition, `thread_local int var = 0;`, is in `main.cpp`.